# Modify column data based on other column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im new to python and pandas
I have a csv with data which im able to read and extract data using pandas as shown below

```
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

I have many columns below is the columns in question

[image]

Here i want to convert the price column into USD equivalent for all the entries.
following is the code which i tried

```
currencyToUSD = {
"USD": 1,
"AUD": 0.7,
"EUR": 1.12,
"HKD": 0.13,
"INR": 0.014,
"KRW": 0.00085
}
for row in data.itertuples():
   data[row.index]['price'] = row.price*currencyToUSD[row.currency]
```

It throws errors, what i want to achieve is to modify the 'price' column based on the value of 'currency' column. Guide me with the right way to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `itertuples` should be omit for improve performance, use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new `Series` for multiple column `price`:

```
data['price'] = data.price*data.currency.map(currencyToUSD)
```